# How to get Event using Online Meeting ID in Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I need to programmatically obtain event details using an Online Meeting ID through the Microsoft Graph API. Is it possible to retrieve the event using the Online Meeting ID, or is there any other approach to obtain event details based on the Online Meeting ID?

Need to get Event using online meeting ID

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Microsoft graph API to get the event details. It shows need to pass event ID
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-event?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: For that i need to retrieve the event ID using the List Events endpoint. My requirement involves obtaining recurring meeting details, but when using the Online Meeting API endpoint, I am unable to retrieve the occurrence ID for recurring meetings. In the Event endpoint, I can obtain the occurrence ID for recurring meetings, but I only have the online meeting ID. Is there an alternative method to obtain event details using the online meeting ID?

Comment: @Hariharan Please check below link for live event details . But seems live event related APIs will get deprecated soon and new endpoints will be released by Microsoft. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-teams-live-events-api-on-microsoft-graph/